# Кнопка Back сворачивает приложение UWP

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, uwp

Я разрабатывал своё приложение для UWP, и сегодня, когда я запустил приложение, обнаружил, что нажатие на кнопку назад на телефоне или эмуляторе, попросту сворачивает приложение. Раньше она возвращала меня назад на страницу с которой я перешёл методом `Frame.Navigate`, а теперь просто сворачивает. Помогла только конструкция вот эта: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/d51f4cb4-d686-4d30-8820-ccbae4326450/uwpwindows10-mobile-back-button?forum=wpdevelop Но и даже она работает криво, она перекидывает на одну страницу больше назад. Кто нибудь может объяснить, что произошло? 
З.Ы В других моих проектах всё работает.

Comment: Покажите код этих двух страниц (только то, что касается навигации).

Comment: @andreycha http://pastebin.com/SsVXAVsc

Comment: код подписки BackPressed покажите?

Comment: @Andrii Krupka Я нигде не подписывал и не подписываю этот ивент. С самого начала, как только я создал приложение в VS2015 я не трогал ничего связанного с навигацией кнопки Назад. И при этом, всё работало и устраивало меня. Что после перехода на любую страницу выше написанным методом, я могу нажать в любое время  кнопку Back, и вернуться на предыдущую страницу.

Comment: @AndriiKrupka Я создал новый проект и там тоже самое. Мне же не могло привидеться, что кнопкой назад я возвращаюсь на предыдущую страницу. У меня есть записи видео, где я снимал процесс приложения, так вот там я спокойно возвращаюсь назад кнопкой back. При этом в коде я тогда ничего не писал по этому поводу.

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего вы путаете приложения UWP и универсальные приложения на базе Windows 8.1
Дело в том, что в 8.1 в логику классов, входящих в шаблон проекта уже была зашита подписка на BackPressed и соответствующее поведение.
Приложения UWP не имеют готового шаблона для того или иного случая, а значит логику навигации вам придется реализовывать самостоятельно. [Тут](https://habrahabr.ru/post/267789/) есть хорошая статья об этом и интересный пример реализации навигации в UWP приложении.